# Asyncronous Task is begin cancelled on touching the screen while it is running?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Asynchronous Task is begin cancelled on touching the screen while it is running.I have tested my application in in **samsung pop** with **android 2.3.6** .In this mobile the Asynchronous task is not get cancelled on touching the screen while it is running.But while i tested it in **Sony u with android 4.0.1**  i touch the screen the Asynchronous task has get cancelled.i have tried to override the touch event with the Asynchronous  status.but it not get fixed.how can we solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution

I use

> dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
>               dialog.setCancelable(false);

```
public class getcatogry extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
            MainActivity.this);

    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        this.dialog.show();
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    // automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
    protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) {
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);






        return null;
    }

    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();




        }
        // reset the output view by retrieving the new data
        // (note, this is a naive example, in the real world it might make
        // sense
        // to have a cache of the data and just append to what is already
        // there, or such
        // in order to cut down on expensive database operations)
        // new SelectDataTask().execute();
    }
}
```

This way the async task will not get canceled even on back press or on touch async task